# Application built using VS2010 does not work in VS-Express2008 - C

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, winapi, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-express

I have wrote an application that consists of two projects in a solution, each project contains only 1 .c source file. I was using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate but due to the University only supporting 2008 I decided to create a blank solution and copy the source files into the new one.

After creating a new solution in VS2008 express, creating two projects and re-creating and adding the source files to the projects I ran the application.

For some reason only one part of the application does not work, I use CreateProcess() to execute "Project1.exe" from Project 2.

This works fine under vs2010 but for some reason it's not working under VS2008 express, GetLastError() is showing an Error 2: File Not Found.

This is an image showing the same code in both IDE's:

[image: Error Image]

I'm not using anything special and I've made sure that both solutions/projects are using .Net 3.5.

I can't work out why it would work for one IDE and not the other.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

**Edit:**

Screenshot of .exe's

[image: .exe location]

Comment: If the error message is "file not found" have you made sure that the exe you are trying to start is actually at the location you are assuming? From the screenshot it seems that you are using a relative path. Is the working folder the same?

Comment: Yup it's the same, I made sure to build each project independently just to make sure the .exe's were created. They are both next to each other in the same folder, that's what makes it weirder.

Comment: Do you start the first exe from within the IDE or from a console window?

Comment: From within the IDE, DiceConsumer.exe is setbas the startup project and from this it calls the CreateProcess in the WM_CREATE message. I went into the Debug folder in the VS2010 build and running DiceConsumer.exe launches DiceProducer.exe fine.

Comment: I would make the guess that it works from the console. Could you check the working folder setting specified in the IDE?

Comment: Hmm, running it from the console seems to work fine. I can't understand how/why that happens and also why it gives me an error 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing the full path name of the .exe to CreateProcess().  This usually only works if you are lucky.  The .exe files would have to be in the same directory and the working directory has to be set to that directory.  First verify that the .exes are where you hope they are.

Avoid the dependency on the working directory by generating the full path to the 2nd .exe.  Use GetModuleFileName(), passing NULL, to get the full path of your 1st .exe

Comment: It worked in VS2010 as both .exe's are in the same folder. I can't specify the paths explicitly as they may be moved. An example being the solution folder is on my desktop now but it may be moved into my documents.

Comment: @Jamie, that's why I recommended you use GetModuleFileName().  It makes your code work no matter where the .exes are located and no matter where the current working directory is pointing.